# Swift 3 references

Tags: reference, swift3

When creating an instance of an object, I'm having trouble setting its properties if I assign the property to another variable.

Eg.  For an object containing nested objects, I want to assign one of the children to a temporary var to make it easier to work with.

Instead of doing this (which works):

```
myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0].property = "something"
```

I'm trying to do:

```
var t = myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0]
t.property = "something" 
// this doesn't throw an error but doesn't change the value of myObj
```

What gives?

Edit>

Here's a contrived example to illustrate:

```
class Car { var name: String = "" }

var merc = Car()
var obj = merc.name

merc.name = "C63 AMG"
obj = "E300"

print("merc.name: \(merc.name)") // prints merc.name: C63 AMG
print("obj.name: \(obj)") // prints obj.name: E300

var ob2 = merc
ob2.name = "Toyota"
print("ob2.name: \(ob2.name)") // prints ob2.name: Toyota
print("merc.name: \(merc.name)") // prints merc.name: Toyota
```

So assigning the class instance to a var creates a reference.  But assigning a property of that object to another var creates a copy?

I read through https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 and still don't get it :(

In the above, 'obj' is not a struct, enum or tuple, so shouldn't it be a reference type?

Comment: Edit your question to show the types of `myObj`, `myChildObj` and `someOtherChild` and someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0]` is a value type (I.e. a strict, direct enum or tuple), it's being copied upon assignment to `t`. Subsequent mutations on `t` only mutate that copy, and the original instance are unchanged.

You would have to reassign `t` back in:

```
var t = myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0]
t.property = "something"
myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0] = t
```

This is discussed in [the Swift language guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  I was just reading up on value vs reference types here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 and it says a reference type will copy a reference to the same object, which is what I'm after.  

In he above case, the objects in the arrays are custom classes, not structs.

What am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you expect me to be able to say, given that you haven't shown what these structures/objects are

Comment: Sorry this is wrong. *Reference* types are not copied on assignment, *value* types are.

Comment: Oops, I misspoke. In future cases, you can just suggest an edit. I've fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I added more detail and example code above.  I'm sure Swift is not broken!  Just my understanding of it.

Comment: I guess this is the bit of Swift law I am experiencing:  "In Swift, Array, String, and Dictionary are all value types".  So my assignment is to the class instance property which is a String and therefore gets copied.

Comment: yes, `Array`, `Dictionary` and `String` are all structs, which are value types. I don't understand your second sentence "So my assignment is to the class instance property which is a String and therefore gets copied."

Comment: In the case of "var obj = merc.name", 'merc.name' is a string type, so that makes sense.  But now after re-reading my original comment, I'm confused again!  In my first example, 'myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0]' is a class object, so assigning that to 't' as I did should be assigning an instance of a class to 't' and therefore creating a reference!?

Comment: If `myObj.myChildObject[0].someOtherChild[0]` is an object, then yes, assigning it to `t` will make `t` a reference to the same existing object, without copying.

Comment: That works perfectly.  Not sure what was wrong with my original code :)  Thanks for your help.